# VB.Net Find and Replace Line By Line Cycling Through File Names from a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, replace, datagridview, line

I was kindly helped before with this code by a guy name Steven, however I have hit yet another stumbling block, I keep messing my loops up.
I have some code that cycles through over 100 ish k of Find and Replaces and i have added into it the ability to cycle through a number of 
files to Find and Replace items within said files, i have used ReadLine and WriteLine otherwise I have memory issues and it bombs out.

With the code below,i can get it to either cycle through and not find and replace or find and replace one of the files and not cycle 
through the rest of the files. Where am i going wrong with the loops, im going insane.  Many thanks, VBvirg

---

'The files to cycle through

```
For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
    If Not row2.IsNewRow Then
        Dim DateFile As String = row2.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        Dim DateFileConv As String = row2.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        Dim fName As String = DateFile
        Dim wrtFile As String = DateFileConv
        Dim strRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
        Dim strWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtFile)


        While True
    'Thesre are the find and replaces
            Dim line As String = strRead.ReadLine()
            If line IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                        Dim Find1 As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                        Dim Replace1 As String = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                        line = line.Replace(Find1, Replace1)

                    End If

                Next
                strWrite.WriteLine(line)

            End If
        End While


    End If
Next

Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
MessageBox.Show("Finished Replacing")
```

Comment: You see that `While True` loop? Well, that never exits (i.e. never leaves the loop). I suspect that is not what you want. Also, you must use `.Dispose()` on the streamreader/writers; you could use a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) construct to take care of that for you.

Comment: Hi Andrew, but if i move the while loops then it creates all of the files instead of find and replacing in one file line by line then moving to the next file.  Im in Loop hell.

Comment: `While True` should probably be `While Not strRead.EndOfStream` so that the loop can finish when it gets to the end of the input file.

Comment: you dropped the EXIT WHILE which used to be in your code

Comment: Top man Andrew thank you so much I can now sleep without dreaming in broken loops :)  thank you again.  I would buy you a pint if i knew where you was.

Comment: I will try that as well Plutonix the more i can learn the better.